# GORM, Inherited model, recursive link

Tags: inheritance, grails, groovy, grails-orm

Assuming that we have books

```
class Book {

   String title
   String type="Book"
   String author
   Book parentBook // <----<<<
   //...
}
```

and we extend books to other types

```
 class ReferenceBook extends Book {

    String type="RefBook"

    void setParentBook(Book b) {
       if ((b && b.type) && (b.type=="RefBook")) {
          parentBook = b
       } else {
          parentBook = null
       }
    }
 }
```

When I do this I get a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when attempting to set a parentBook for ReferenceBook.

I know I'm missing something here...

Answer (score 1):

use discriminator feature:

```
  class Book {
   String title
   String author
   Book parentBook // <----<<<
   //...
   static mapping = {
     tablePerHierarchy false
     discriminator column:[name:"discriminator", length:200, value:'Book']
   }
  }

class ReferenceBook extends Book {
  //...
  static mapping = {
    discriminator column:[value:'RefBook']
  }
  void setParentBook(Book b) {
    parentBook = ('RefBook' == b?.properties['class']) ? b : null
  }
```

}